# Why am I measuring the power different than the given rated power?

Tags: power, solenoid

There is a [solenoid-valve](https://www.burkert.com/en/Media/plm/MAN/MA/MA0280-UL-EU-EN.pdf?id=MAN0000000000000001000010128ENJ) where I measure its resistance as 55 Ohm across its terminals. The photo of its label is shown below:

[image]

Above it says 24V DC 8W. But I measure the solenoid's DC resistance as 55 Ohm and from P = V^2/R this corresponds to (24^2)/55 = 10.5 W.
But the label says it is 8W. What can be the reason?

Comment: You aren't measuring power.  You've measured the coil resistance at a (very) low current - which is likely quite different from what it will be when operating at full power.

Comment: Actually I juts made an experiment and when the solenoid is energized the current starts like 0.38 ampere and gradually in 5 seconds drops to 0.34 ampere this means the resistance is increasing and settling to a value. So your comment is correct. But I didn't get why it takes so long time for current to settle.

Comment: @cm64 The windings heat up, and as the temperature rises so the resistance also rises. Leave it on 24V For 30 minutes or so and then take it off and measure it, you will likely find the resistance is somewhat higher then it is when it is cold (More so if it is working with a fluid at 90C), these are not precision devices in this respect, and I would read the datasheet as "run it at 24V and use a driver capable of half an amp or so".

Answer (score 2):

The Buerkert solenoid valve is listed in RS as having an RS part number of [337-5521](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/solenoid-valves/3375521/) and, on that page there is a data sheet that tells you that the holding power is 8 watts and this means you can relax the drive voltage from 24 volts to something a bit lower and keep the solenoid operated.

So, assuming 55 ohms is an accurate measurement of resistance, the voltage required to achieve 8 watts is more like 21 volts. If you maintained operation at 24 volts then the power would be the 10.5 watts you calculate.

Comment: Thanks I also have another related question  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/424307/would-this-parallel-led-lamp-upset-the-working-of-the-flywheel-diode